# env: sh\r: No such file or directory (React Native)

Tags: react-native

Recently I have move from windows to macbook and i want to run my project. What happen with this error "env: sh\r: No such file or directory"? I have been success to create a new project but open my last project have this error. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This fixes it:

```
dos2unix android/gradlew
```